# Сортировка массива на основе данных другого массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Помогите найти оптимальный способ сортировки массива на основе другого массива.

Имеется массив с объектами:

```
const data = [
  {id_ves: "ID"}, 
  {date: "Дата"}, 
  {permit: "Разрешение"}, 
  {rank: "Категория"}
]
```

Необходимо сделать сортировку объектов в массиве data в соответствии со значением ключа каждого свойства массива orders:

```
const orders = [
      {id_ves: 2}, 
      {date: 4}, 
      {permit: 1}, 
      {rank: 3}
    ]
```

Конечный результат должен быть таким:

```
 const data = [
      {permit: "Разрешение"},
      {id_ves: "ID"},
      {rank: "Категория"} 
      {date: "Дата"},  
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data =   [{id_ves: "ID"}, {date: "Дата"}, {permit: "Разрешение"}, {rank: "Категория"}]
const orders = [{id_ves: 2},    {date: 4},      {permit: 1},            {rank: 3}          ]

// Добавляем свойство `order` для всех объектов из `data`.
data.forEach(function(item, index) {
  // Получаем первый ключ из ключей свойств объекта.
  let firstKey = Object.keys(item)[0]

  // Ищем `order`, у которого есть свойство с переданным ключом.
  let finded = orders.find(order => order.hasOwnProperty(firstKey))

  // Добавляем свойство.
  item.order = finded[firstKey]
})

// Сортировка массива `data` по значению одного из свойств.
data.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)

// Распечатаем результат.
secondResult.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre id="secondResult"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
    { id_ves: "ID" },
    { date: "Дата" },
    { permit: "Разрешение" },
    { rank: "Категория" }
];

const orders = [
    { id_ves: 2 },
    { date: 4 },
    { permit: 1 },
    { rank: 3 }
];

orders.sort((a, b) => values(a)[0] - values(b)[0]);

data.sort((a, b) => orders.findIndex((el) => keys(el)[0] == keys(a)[0]) - orders.findIndex((el) => keys(el)[0] == keys(b)[0]));
```

Помимо массива **data**, также сортируется массив **orders**, если это не критично - решение рабочее.